# Tomcat error page using bookmarkable pages in Wicket

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket, web.xml

I have such an issue.

I need to show customized error page, when receive 404 HTTP error. I`m using Wicket 1.4 and Tomcat6. I have implemented these things in web.xml, like

```xml
 <filter-name>wicket.filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>         
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

and placed in such code in my WebApplication:

```java
mount(new HybridUrlCodingStrategy("/404", PageNotFound.class));
```

PageNotFound class isErrorPage set true, isVersioned false and

```java
    @Override
    protected void configureResponse() {
       super.configureResponse();   
       getWebRequestCycle().getWebResponse().getHttpServletResponse().setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

Now the problem is, that when I enter some invalid url, like `http://localhost:8080/myApp-war/invalidUrl`, I can see my PageNotFound.
But when I enter something like `http://localhost:8080/myApp-war/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:com.mypackage.invalidUrl`, then I just get empty clear page without any data.

I have noticed, that at first situation tomcat shows just "*HTTP Status 404 - /myApp-war/invalidUrl*"
and in the other case it shows slightly different message : "*HTTP Status 404 - Unable to load Bookmarkable Page*"

How is it possible to make both cases show the same page? Maybe this `<error-page>` tag needs to be modified? I`ll provide you with more information, if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and your expectations are perfect. It is just a Wicket bug or Tomcat wrong understanding of 404 Exception. I guess it is just in Wicket prior to 1.4.x version.

The fix is to override the code in **AbstractRequestCycleProcessor**, you can override it just in the factory method of your WebApplication class:

```
@Override

protected IRequestCycleProcessor newRequestCycleProcessor() {

return new WebRequestCycleProcessor() {

    @Override
    protected IRequestTarget resolveBookmarkablePage(final RequestCycle requestCycle,
            final RequestParameters requestParameters) {
        IRequestTarget target = super.resolveBookmarkablePage(requestCycle, requestParameters);
        if(target == null) {
            return target;
        }
        if(target instanceof WebErrorCodeResponseTarget) {
            WebErrorCodeResponseTarget errorResponse = (WebErrorCodeResponseTarget) target;
            if(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND == errorResponse.getErrorCode()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return target;
    }

};
```

}

I place the full working example into my Wicket14 testing repository https://repo.twinstone.org/projects/WISTF/repos/wicket-examples-1.4/browse